# LaTeX missing reference

Tags: cross-referencing

A weird, possibly trivial, problem is happening.

After running `pdflatex test` with the following in the file **test.tex**

```
% -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
We greet in Figure~\ref{myfig}.

\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering\large hello
  \label{myfig}
  \caption{greet}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

one time, I find in the file **test.aux**, as expected:

```
\relax 
\newlabel{myfig}{{}{1}}
```

and I duly get warned that:

```
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.

LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.
```

But after a second run of `pdflatex test`, the number `1` does not appear where it should

[image: missing reference]

and the warning no longer appears, suggesting all is well.

Where should I be looking?

(I've tried:

- Deleting the aux file and recompiling.
- Using xelatex and lualatex.

)

I'm using TeX Live 2015 on El Capitan.

Comment: it has always been that way and is the most frequently of frequently asked questions on latex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your problem is independend from your used operating system and `tex` distribution.

It is important to write first `\caption`, then `\label`.  Please have for example an look to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34933/how-to-understand-the-latex-warning-there-were-undefined-references?rq=1) or take a look to the LaTeX companion or other LaTeX documentations.

So with the follwing MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
We greet in Figure~\ref{myfig}.

\begin{figure}
  \centering\large hello
  \caption{greet}
  \label{myfig}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

you will get no errors or warnings after two compile runs or more.  Please see that I deleted the option `[h]` for your `figure` environment.  Please use this option only if it is really needed and btw only using `[h]` will cause an warning, you should then, only if needed, `[ht]` or simular.

Comment: I think of the caption as optional, and indeed in some styles, it is. But it still makes sense to increment the counter within \caption{}. If the caption is omitted, it's assumed that the figure's location will be rigidly monitored and that the reference to the figure will be informal.

Comment: @Calaf: Without `\caption` (or `\captionof{figure}`) there's no increment of the `figure` counter (and nothing that displays the value of the figure counter, i.e `\thefigure`. A manual increment within `caption` is not recommended

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I didn't express myself well. I didn't mean that I would increment the counter myself, just that it gets incremented as a side effect of executing \caption{}. The style I'm thinking of (figures and text are interspersed, with no references or captions) is a variation on using package wrapfig.