# How to pinpoint the lines and/or the lables causing the LaTeX warning "There were undefined references"?

Tags: cross-referencing, warnings

After compiling my LaTeX document, the log file contains the message:

> LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.

How can I tell which lines and/or labels prompted this warning?

PS This question has already been asked in [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34933/how-to-understand-the-latex-warning-there-were-undefined-references#comment608350_38076) by some other user, and the reply was that the person asking the question should ask it in a separate post, but I haven't been able to find any post that addresses this question.

Comment: The log file contains also the exact line with the undefined reference.

Comment: @campa: No, it doesn't.

Comment: What you quote is the final warning, but scrolling up the log file you'll see `Reference XXX on page XXX undefined on input line XXX`.

Comment: @campa: You're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message `There were undefined references` is one of the last things printed on screen to catch your attention to the issue. However, scrolling up to the console output or the log file will show the line number where the undefined reference was found. The file

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{foo}\label{foo}
This is section \ref{fo}
\end{document}
```

returns

```
LaTeX Warning: Reference `fo' on page 1 undefined on input line 4.

[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./mwe.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
```

Of course, if after the undefined reference there are many pages, possibly with figures, you might have to scroll back a lot.

---

If you `\input` external files then you must keep in mind that the quoted line number always refers to the *current*  file. Assume that we have a file `foo.tex`

```
\section{foo}\label{foo}
This is section \ref{fo}
```

and the main file `main.tex` reads

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Text text.
\input{foo}
\end{document}
```

then the log will contain

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/TeX Live for SUSE Linux) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.9.25)  9 APR 2021 14:59
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**main.tex
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>

% [ ... other stuff ... ]

 (./foo.tex

LaTeX Warning: Reference `fo' on page 1 undefined on input line 2.

) [1

{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./mwe.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.

 )
% [ ... other stuff ...]
```

Here the line number refers to the *external* file: watch out for the string `(./foo.tex` which means that this is the currently open file. The corresponding closing parenthesis `)` is shown just after the warning; the final closing parenthesis refers to the main file (the corresponding opening one is on the 6th line).