# Where to put the \label on a figure environment?

Tags: cross-referencing, captions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does an environment’s label have to appear after the caption?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32325/why-does-an-environments-label-have-to-appear-after-the-caption)

I noticed that when I put the `\label` command before the `\caption` command in a figure environment, I get wrong `\ref` results for this figure. When I put the label in or after the `\caption`, the `\ref` will work fine. In the first case, I will get a `\ref` to the enclosing section (or subsection). Why is that so? And is there some documentation which tells me how to label a figure correctly?

Comment: I always put the labels in the captions too. As far as I know the consensus is to do this to ensure proper references. I've seen odd advice for labels in general though. Recently I came across the notion that labels for sections should be in the section command itself, which seems very odd.

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt: Labels should be _in_ the commands. Leslie Lamport says so. `:-)`

Comment: I really should read the manuals from days of yore!

Comment: Thanks everyone for the insight. As a user I thought that I was putting a label on a figure environment, but instead I am really putting a label on a caption. That's good to know. However I concur with Mark that putting the \label command inside of a \section looks weird. Even if Mr Lamport says so, it does not mean it's the user friendliest solution. :)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The `\label` always has to be placed *after* (or within) the caption, as it is `\caption` that increases the counter related to figures. `\label` will refer to the last counter that was "active", so by placing it before the caption it will refer to the last sectioning command instead.