# Referencing figures doesn't work

Tags: floats, cross-referencing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where to put the \label on a figure environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35137/where-to-put-the-label-on-a-figure-environment)

I'm having a problem with referencing figures in LaTeX. I have the following text:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\center
\label{fig:enn1015}
\includegraphics[scale=0.40]{imagens/outputs/ENN_10_15.eps}
\caption{ENN unbalanced 10\%}
\end{figure}

The figure \ref{fig:enn1015} (...)
```

For some reason, the figure caption is:

```
Figure 3.5 Enn unbalanced 10%
```

But the text is:

```
The figure 3.2.1 (...)
```

Instead of:

```
The figure 3.5
```

It is printing the chapter.section.subsection the figure is in, and not the figure. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Try putting your `\label{}` statement immediately after your `\caption{}` statement.

**Edit**: I'm not a total expert on how the `\label` command works, but I think it assigns a label to the last-seen "labelable" thing, so you want it right after your caption, which is "labelable" (my terminology). Currently, it is labeling whatever the last "labelable" thing was before your figure, probably a section heading or something (hence the 3.2.1).

**2nd Edit**: In other words, and maybe this is kind of counter-intuitive, you can't label *figures*; you must label *captions*.

Comment: If I want to label a figure, but I don't want to include a caption, how can I create an empty caption that takes no space to use with a label?