# Reference from a different folder

Tags: cross-referencing, folders

I'm writing my thesis and have trouble reference labels between chapters.
My main folder look like this:

- Main Folder, where I have the main tex file and folders where I have
  the main tex file and folders

  1. main tex file, where the documentclass, userpackage, etc are located. With the 
     \makechapter{The First Chapter} \input{Chapter1/chapter1.tex}
     \makechapter{The Second Chapter} \input{Chapter2/chapter2.tex}
  2. Chapter1 (Folder, where inside the file i write in)
     chapter1.tex
  3. Chapter2 (Folder, where inside the file i write in)
     chapter2.tex

When I write in chapter1.tex

```
\section(Chapter One) \label(Ch1)      
\begin{equation} \label{eq:1}    
a^2 + b^2 = c^2    
\end{equation}
```

How can I in chapter2.tex file, reference the labels in chapter1, which is located in a file located in another folder?, for example when I write in chapter2.tex,
As equation `\lable(eq:1)` in chapter `\lable(Ch1)` show.

Because now it just shows [??]

Comment: The chapter work but I can't ref to the equation

Comment: The linking works for me. But you could try this.
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37452/referencing-figures-doesnt-work

Answer (score 1):

Technically, this should work (if not, post your MWE). See the following MWE.

main.tex

```
   documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

   \begin{document}

    \input{ch1/ch1.tex}
    \input{ch2/ch2.tex}

   \end{document}
```

now, ch1.tex

```
\chapter{ch1}
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:1}
x= x \,
\end{equation}
```

and ch2.tex

```
\chapter{ch2}
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:2}
x= x \,
\end{equation}

Eq.~\ref{eq:1} ...
```

produces, following ---

[image]