# Cannot label a wrapfigure

Tags: wrapfigure, nameref

I have the following environment to display a sidebar:

```
\newcommand{\dummy}{}

\newenvironment*{lsidebar}[2][0.5]
{
    \renewcommand{\dummy}{#1}

    \wrapfigure{l}{#1\textwidth}
        \rule{#1\textwidth}{1pt}

        \rule{#1\textwidth}{18pt}

        \vspace{-18pt}
        \centerline{\textcolor{white}{#2}}

        \vspace{5pt}
        \footnotesize
        \leftskip=5pt
        \rightskip=5pt
        \setlength{\parskip}{0.2cm}
        \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

}
{
        \leftskip=0pt
        \rightskip=0pt
        \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
        \rule{\dummy\textwidth}{1pt}
        \rule[.19in]{\dummy\textwidth}{2.5pt}
    \endwrapfigure
}
```

I use the environment like this:

```
\begin{lsidebar}{Example Sidebar}
    \label{sb:Example}

    An example sidebar.
\end{lsidebar}

Refer to sidebar \nameref*{sb:Example}.
```

It renders how I want it to. However, the label does not resolve as expected when using `\nameref*{sb:Example}`. Instead of displaying the sidebar's title, it displays the chapter title:

[image]

Here is a complete repro:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{color}

\newcommand{\dummy}{}

\newenvironment*{lsidebar}[2][0.5]
{
    \renewcommand{\dummy}{#1}

    \wrapfigure{l}{#1\textwidth}
        \rule{#1\textwidth}{1pt}

        \rule{#1\textwidth}{18pt}

        \vspace{-18pt}
        \centerline{\textcolor{white}{#2}}

        \vspace{5pt}
        \footnotesize
        \leftskip=5pt
        \rightskip=5pt
        \setlength{\parskip}{0.2cm}
        \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

}
{
        \leftskip=0pt
        \rightskip=0pt
        \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
        \rule{\dummy\textwidth}{1pt}
        \rule[.19in]{\dummy\textwidth}{2.5pt}
    \endwrapfigure
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}
\label{ch:First}

\begin{lsidebar}{Example Sidebar}
    \label{sb:Example}

    An example sidebar.
\end{lsidebar}

Refer to sidebar \nameref*{sb:Example}.

\end{document}
```

Can anyone tell me how to resolve the name/title of the sidebar instead of the chapter?

Comment: Referencing figures only works with a `\caption` command. So, if you add `\caption{}` to the first argument of `\newenvironment*` somewhere after `\wrapfigure`, it should work.

Comment: @marmot thanks for that! I'm a LaTeX newb, in case it isn't obvious. If you want to add that as an answer, I'll happily accept.

Comment: Thanks, but this question already has an answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37452/referencing-figures-doesnt-work). I forgot to add the link to my comment above, sorry.