# Referencing Captionless Figure?

Tags: cross-referencing, wrapfigure

I want to be able to reference a captionless figure (e.g. `\ref{figure1}`). Based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37453/168614), it appears that labeling a figure (e.g. `\label{figure1}`) actually labels the **caption**. How do I reference my captionless figure? I tried adding an empty caption (e.g. `\caption{}`) but this create an undesired `Figure 1`.

Comment: You wrote, "it appears that labeling a figure (e.g. \label{figure1}) actually labels the caption." That's not entirely correct. The `\label` mechanism latches on to the most recently incremented counter variable. It so happens that `\caption` directives do increment a counter variable (called `figure` or `table`, resp., depending on whether the `\caption` directive is encountered [pun intended] in a `figure` or `table` environment). But that's not the same as saying that the caption is labelled. Please clarify what you intend a cross-reference to a captionless figure to look like/consist of.

Comment: I want to have a figure without a caption, and I want to be able to reference the figure. That's basically it. Currently when I try adding a label to the figure, and then referencing that label someplace else, nothing appears.