# label for table

Tags: tables, numbering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where to put the \label on a figure environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35137/where-to-put-the-label-on-a-figure-environment)

I've got the table numberin with sections:

```
\numberwithin{table}{section}
```

The following table is 2.1. for example:

```
\begin{table}
...
\label{thelabel}
\end{table}
```

But when I reference this table using `\ref{thelabel}` I only get the 2, not the whole table number.

How to get the label and the table number right?

Comment: Is the `\label` *after* `\caption`? Yes, you need `\caption` in order to be able to reference it properly.

Comment: Shame on me! Your hint was just right Werner, it pointed me to a stupid mistake. Sorry. Can be closed.

Answer (score 2):

The `\label` should go after the `\caption` in the float (`table` or `figure`) in order for the referencing to work properly.