# Using \label within a figure float

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, labels

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where to put the \label on a figure environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35137/where-to-put-the-label-on-a-figure-environment)

My question is rather simple. I have noticed that when I use `\label` like this

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Leslie_Lamport}
\label{fig:LL}
\caption{Leslie Lamport}
\end{figure}
```

and then refer to this label it refers rather to the section number than to the figure (I've seen it been refered as `section.figurenumber` but that was due to a package I believe - possibly `hyperref`). But when using it after the caption

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Leslie_Lamport}
\caption{Leslie Lamport}
\label{fig:LL}
\end{figure}
```

it really refers to the figure number.

Can someone explain the mechanic behind \label to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `\label{fig:LL}` inside the `\caption{}` tag.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Leslie_Lamport}
\caption{Leslie Lamport\label{fig:LL}}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Why, just place it after `\caption`