# Wrong reference for figures?

Tags: cross-referencing, captions, lncs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does an environment's label have to appear after the caption?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32325/why-does-an-environments-label-have-to-appear-after-the-caption)
>   [Where to put the \label on a figure environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35137/where-to-put-the-label-on-a-figure-environment)

I use `\documentclass{llncs}`, when I reference an image labelled for example "img1" using `\ref{img1}` I get the number of the section instead of the number of the image ! After that I added `\usepackage[compatibility=false]{caption}` because I need it for another problem, and I see now that if I do `\ref{img1}` I get nothing else "??" !

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: @doncherry Well the problem is simply: when I use the `llncs` class, the references of figures are not the number of the figure but the number of the section in which the figure is inserted.

Comment: I realize it may be trivial, but as @doncherry commented, it is best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  Basically, it is better to show the problem rather than describe the problem.

Comment: It sounds very much like you issue the `\label` command *before* the `\caption` command. Check for this and, if it's the case, be sure to reverse the ordering. At any rate, do post a MWE (minimum working example) so that others might have a chance to diagnose -- and, subsequently, propose a solution for -- the problem you're encountering.

Comment: @Mico you are right, thanks ! The problem is that I used `\label` command before `\caption` command

Comment: @user995434 which is why you should have given a minimal example ... then nobody has to guess. An MWE is not to describe the problem (you did fine) it is to get a clue what might be the cause .. as often the problem sits in front of the computer so to speak