# Reference to the table does not appear

Tags: cross-referencing

Although I have a valid label for a table, the reference to that label does not appear in the PDF file, or sometimes appear as `??` if I put a tilde before `\ref`.

The code is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!t]
\footnotesize
\parbox{.50\linewidth}{
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l|l}
Example plot \\ \hline
A & 22 \% \\ 
B & 54 \% \\
\end{tabular}
}
\label{tab:example}
\caption{Example plot}
\end{table}

Looking the table \ref{tab:example}


\end{document}
```

Any thought?

Comment: The most frequently asked question of all time: put the \label after \caption otherwise you are labelling the section or as here nothing at all, rather than the caption.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Have a look at [Table numbering mismatch in caption and in text](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23385), [Wrong reference for figures?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61856), [Why does an environment's label have to appear after the caption?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32325), [Where to put the \label on a figure environment?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35137)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. And David is right, I guess your question will be closed soon as a duplicate.

Comment: It works. Thanks! But I wonder why it worked in another latex template with the order above.