# LaTeX figure cross reference label using RStudio and knitr

Tags: knitr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does an environment’s label have to appear after the caption?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32325/why-does-an-environments-label-have-to-appear-after-the-caption)
>   [Where to put the \label on a figure environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35137/where-to-put-the-label-on-a-figure-environment)

When using RStudio to write a .Rnw file, I find that when inserting a plot, the cross reference is not expected. For example, in section 5.3 I insert a plot using the following commands:

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\begin{center}\label{fig:testplot}
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{testplot.pdf}
\caption{I'm caption}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

In the text, I write "In Figure~`\ref{fig:testplot}`" to reference this plot. However, after clicking Compile PDF, I find that what produced is "In Figure 5.3" --> it is the section number, not the desired figure number (it should print out Figure 4 since three figures already existed in the text). What went wrong?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Try to put the `\label` *after* the `\includegraphics`.

Comment: @Dror: thanks, but it still doesn't work...