# Why am I getting errors about defined references?

Tags: floats, cross-referencing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does an algorithm's label have to appear after the caption?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32325/why-does-an-algorithms-label-have-to-appear-after-the-caption)

I have the following in a paper:

```
See~\ref{fig:quicksort}.

\begin{figure}
    \label{fig:quicksort}
    \begin{algorithm}[H]
        \caption*{\textsc{QuickSort}(\emph{Array, Left, Right})}
        \label{alg:quicksort}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \If{$Left < Right$}
                \State PivotIndex $\gets$ \textsc{Partition}(\emph{Array, Left, Right})
                \State \textsc{QuickSort}(\emph{Array, Left,} $PivotIndex - 1$)
                \State \textsc{QuickSort}(\emph{Array,} $PivotIndex + 1,$ \emph{Right})
            \EndIf
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
    \caption{\small{\textbf{Serial Implementation of the In-Place Quicksort Algorithm} - Brief Description}}
\end{figure}
```

I must have compiled this *at least twenty times* now but I still get errors about undefined references and I get a nice litte **??** in my document. What am I doing wrong here?

I am using the following packages: `fullpage`, `algorithm`, `algpseudocode`, and `caption`.

Screenshot of document in progress:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It's quite strange to have an `algorithm` environment inside a `figure`. However, the `\label` command must go *after* the caption it should refer to.

Comment: See if `\floatstyle{plain} \restylefloat{algorithm}` in the preamble does what you want.