# Why are my reference numbers to labels disappearing?

Tags: cross-referencing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does an environment's label have to appear after the caption?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32325/why-does-an-environments-label-have-to-appear-after-the-caption)

In the following example, there are no reference numbers to the figures when I compile using pdflatex:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}

%debugging package for figuring out why my figure references keep disappearing
%\usepackage{refcheck}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\label{bob}
\caption{Bob}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\label{jane}
\caption{Jane}
\end{figure}

Bob is reference \ref{bob}. Jane is reference \ref{jane}.

\end{document}
```

Any idea why?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: @Jake Indeed. And I'm eagerly awaiting the day stackexchange starts handing out reputation and/or badges for finding duplicates.

Answer (score 7):

You need to put `\label` *after* `\caption`.