# \ref{} does not find my \label in LaTeX

Tags: floats, cross-referencing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does an environment's label have to appear after the caption?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32325/why-does-an-environments-label-have-to-appear-after-the-caption)

I have a problem using `\ref{}` to reference table floating object. In my document, I have a table area like this:

```
\begin{table}
\label{tab:gstexp}
\begin{tabular}{l l p{7.5cm}}
\hline
\hline
\textbf{Nr.}    & \textbf{Name}                     & \textbf{Comment} \\
\hline
   %Contents
\hline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{just a table}
\end{table}
```

In my text, I reference it using `Table~\ref{tab:gstexp}` The ref is before the label in my text but this should be indifferent. But if I compile my code in the PDF it renders "Table ??" instead of "Table 1".

I am using MacTeX and texmaker to compile my documents.

Comment: The `\label` has *always* to be placed *after* the `\caption` command.

Comment: Also it will always show as ?? the first run, you need to run latex a second time to resolve all the references.

Comment: @ThorstenDonig well, but I got the same problem if place it after the '\caption' and if I place it before the caption sometimes it works as well. ???

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, I tried also three or four run's.

Comment: As usually requested on this site you will need to make a full document that people can run. But \label has to be after \caption and latex will need to run twice. Also make sure the pdf you are viewing is being refreshed, some pdf viewers block the file from being updated so you have to close the pdf view before running latex.

Comment: OK, right there has been two problems, I have really to place the \label after the \caption. But in addition, after using the "clean" option in texmaker the problems occurs (even if \label is after \caption). I have to run "Tools" -> "Asymptote" now I changed the Quick Build Option (in "Preferences"->"Quick Build") from "PdfLaTeX + View PDF" to "PdfLaTeX + Asymptote + PdfLaTeX + View PDF" now it seems to work fine.

Comment: On this basis, the question is 'too localized'.