# Latex: Reference label individual images within figure

Tags: labels

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does an environment's label have to appear after the caption?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32325/why-does-an-environments-label-have-to-appear-after-the-caption)

I currently have:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.3\textwidth}
    \vspace{-20pt}
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{images/accumstatic}
        \label{accumst}
    \end{center}
    \vspace{-20pt}
    \caption{Accum static picture}
    \vspace{10pt}
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{images/accumdynamic}
        \label{accumdy}
    \end{center}
    \vspace{-20pt}
    \caption{Accum dynamic picture}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

This creates a page that looks something like:

```
lorum ipsum trees freasa lorum ipsum trees freasa
lorum ipsum trees freasa lorum ##################
lorum ipsum trees freasa lorum #                #
lorum ipsum trees freasa lorum #     Fig.1      #
lorum ipsum trees freasa lorum #                #
lorum ipsum trees freasa lorum ##################
lorum ipsum trees freasa lorum #                #
lorum ipsum trees freasa lorum #     Fig.2      #
lorum ipsum trees freasa lorum #                #
lorum ipsum trees freasa lorum ##################
lorum ipsum trees freasa lorum ipsum trees freasa
```

I then reference it using the cleverref package:

`\paragraph{blah blah blah \cref{accumst}, blah blah blah \cref{accumdy}}`
Unforutantely `accumdy` references the top image (Fig.1) and `accumst` references the previous section number...

How do I get \label{} to see that wrapfigure contains two images?

Comment: This is a common problem in referencing captions with labels. You must place the `\label` after the `\caption`. See [Why does an environment's label have to appear after the caption?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32325/5764)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/5764) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be noted that the `\label` should come after the `\caption`. Hence put the label after the caption to get it right.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig,lipsum,cleveref}
%------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
This is where the table goes with text wrapping around it. You may
embed tabular environment inside wraptable environment and customize as you like.
%------------------------------------------
\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.3\textwidth}
    \vspace{-20pt}
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{images/accumstatic}            
    \vspace{-20pt}
    \caption{Accum static picture}\label{accumst}
    \end{center}
    \vspace{10pt}
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{images/accumdynamic}            
    \vspace{-20pt}
    \caption{Accum dynamic picture}\label{accumdy}
    \end{center}
\end{wrapfigure}
%------------------------------------------
This is where the table goes with text wrapping around it. You may
embed tabular environment inside wraptable environment and customize as you like. This is where the table goes with text wrapping around it. You may
embed tabular environment inside wraptable environment and customize as you like. This is where the table goes with text wrapping around it.
%
\lipsum[2-7]

\paragraph{blah blah blah \cref{accumst}, blah blah blah \cref{accumdy}} 
%------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you -- sorry it took so long for me to vote correct