# \ref not working with tikz and externalize lib

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does an environment's label have to appear after the caption?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32325/why-does-an-environments-label-have-to-appear-after-the-caption)

I am using `tikz` with its externalize library. I create figures with the
following coding style:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  code code code..
\end{tikzpicture}
\label{fig:label}
\caption{Blah blah blah text.}
\end{figure}
```

when I use `\ref{fig:label}` it does not display the correct number. Another notable and bizarre behavior is that the number is in the format, e.g 5.2.1 and not 5.2; has anyone encountered this?

Also by trying to create a MWE I could not make the thing to even appear.
I am not trying to do complex stuff, just to say "in the figure x.x ...". Anyway,
here is the not working MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz} %pgf-tikz pakcage
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,linktocpage,bookmarksopen=true
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[fill = blue,fill opacity = 0.3](0,2) rectangle (1.5,3.5);
\draw[fill = yellow,fill opacity = 0.3](0.5,2.5) rectangle (1,3);

\draw[->] (0.75,0.75) -- (0.75,2.75);
\end{tikzpicture}
\label{fig:stuff}
\end{figure}

Hello \ref{fig:stuff} world
\end{document}
```

Comment: Put `\label` *after* `\caption`.

Comment: That's it. I switched positions and it worked like a charm. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you should put  figure label after caption