# How to use nag?

Tags: nag

I've just added `\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}` to a big document (200+ pages, 100+ images) about computer science. My `.log`-file was 3119 lines long before, now it is 4349 lines long.

**How can I use nag?** Should I really go through 4000+ lines and check everything? There is a lot of noise (info messages by other packages) and I miss relevant information (file where the error happened).

**Can I assume that the following transformations are safe?** Or will quite probably something go wrong if I automatically make these transformations:

- `eqnarray` -> `align` (12 times, [seems to be safe](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/maths/eqnarray-align-environment/))
- old LaTeX 2.09 commands

  - `\bf` -> `\textbf` (27 times)
  - `\rm` -> `\textrm` (3 times)
  - `\it` -> `\textit` (2 times)
- `center`-environment in figure -> `\centering` ([seems to be safe](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/layout/center-centering/), 164 times)
- `center`-environment in table -> `\centering` ([seems to be safe](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/layout/center-centering/), 13 times)
- `h` float specifier -> `ht` (Latex seems to do this automatically, so I guess it is safe, 42 times)
- `\label` in float, but not after `\caption` -> change order (5 times)
- `\usepackage{a4wide}` -> `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{diss-report}` (this is my current document class. So do I have to change anything?)

**Is there a tool that automatically does those transformations?**

Comment: They all seem to be safe (as in "the document will compile"). But some of them (most notably `a4wide`) will probably change the way your document looks.

Comment: The order between `\label` and `\caption` is more than safe, since putting the label before the caption won't work. See for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32325/

Comment: All of those changes look well worth doing, any text editor ought to be able to do those quite easily. in the case of `[h]` note changing it to `[ht]` is not the same as the default recovery that LaTeX will do and it would be better to use `[htp]` as omitting `p` makes float placement a lot harder.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

All those transformations look like a good idea (although they may change your document, the expected change is for the better)  however

`\bf` should be changed to `\bfseries` rather than `\textbf` as the calling syntax for `\textbf` is different (it takes an argument) similarly the other two letter font commands.

As noted in comments it is better to change `[h]` to `[htp]`.

When changing `eqnarray` to `align` take care to delete one `&` from each row, the syntax being `a&=b` rather than `a&=&b`.

Comment: Query-replacing `"{\bf "` with `"\textbf{"` would work as well.

Comment: I've just seen that it is not `[h]` but `[!h]`. Is it also better to write `[!htp]` instead of `[!h]`? (By the way, my log message is now only 3582 lines long :-) )

Comment: @moose yes although you should only rarely need `!` If you are habitually using `!` something is wrong (it means you are setting constraints then saying to ignore them: better to set the correct constraints in the first place)

Comment: @T.Verron Not all uses of `\bf` will necessarily have a preceding `{` and not all instances of `{\bf` may be replaced by `\textbf{` as the scope may include multiple paragraphs.