# Label and Reference Fig

Tags: cross-referencing

As we `$\label{eq01}$` equations and `$ref{eq01}$`, after inserting a image where I mention the label? and how to refer the FIG?

A code I inserted in `LaTeX` for inserting Fig is:

```
\begin{figure}
 \centering
 \includegraphics[scale=0.40]{d2spherical.png}
 % d2spherical.png: 800x300 pixel, 72dpi, 18x8 cm, bb=0 0 1142 479
 \caption{Solution of the spherical equation for $D=2$}
 \label{Fig:5}
\end{figure}
```

Please mention, where to refer and label.

Comment: your code should work fine- you can refer to it using `\ref{Fig:5}`. provided you keep the `\label` *after* the `\caption`, everything will be fine. it's good practice to make your `labels` *descriptive* rather than numeric. For example, you might be better served using `\label{fig:sperical}`. Also, you can (and probably should) omit the file extension in your `includegraphics` command.

Comment: You would `\ref` just the same as you would an equation. See [Why does an environment's label have to appear after the caption?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32325/5764)

Comment: a better syntax for cross-referencing an equation is `\eqref{eq01}`.  (the code shown in the question won't work, as no command is given.  probably a typo.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Referencing is done as in my MWE below.

Some remarks on your example:

- as mentioned by @cmhughes, you should omit the ".png" in your `\includegraphics` command. It will search the best file extension by itself. If you are doing some graphic conversions later on, you don't have to change that. (But it is of course not a mistake...)
- In your text you are labeling inside `$$`. That doesn't make sense as you don't have any equation number to refer to.

---

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[%
    ,demo
    ]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
This is my reference to the figure \ref{fig:Figure} and this the reference to the equation \ref{eq:Equation}.
%
\begin{figure}
 \centering
 \includegraphics[scale=0.40]{d2spherical}
 \caption{Solution of the spherical equation for $D=2$}
 \label{fig:Figure}
\end{figure}
%
\begin{equation}
a^2+b^2=c^2
\label{eq:Equation}
\end{equation}
%
\end{document}
```