# Cleveref breakup on figure references

Tags: floats, errors, cross-referencing, cleveref

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvips]{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev,nameinlink]{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\section{Abc}
\begin{figure}
\label{fig:a}
\centering
\rule{20mm}{20mm}
\caption{abc}
\end{figure}
In \cref{fig:a} $\ldots$
\end{document}
```

From this example you expect an expansion of the sentence

> In \cref{fig:a} $\ldots$

into

> In Figure 1 ...

however on my system this compiles to either `??` (for unknown reference) or gets a chapter, section or subsection 1 reference depending on other labels used in the text. However other types of `cref` references like references to a table, section, listing, etc work as expected even when used with other classes and compilers. Is this a bug in `cleveref`, are there solutions, or is their an error in my setup?

Comment: You need to put the `label` after the `caption`- this fixes the issue, and your question seems like a duplicate of [Why does an environment's label have to appear after the caption?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32325) Let us know, and we'll close it :) As your code stands, the `label` is applied to the most recent 'thing' that has a counter, which in your code is a `section`, hence the confusion

Comment: You are right, thanks for the response, stupid me. Indeed this topic can be closed.

Comment: Don't worry about it :)