# Reference to listing not working

Tags: cross-referencing

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

A nice paper has the following things:

\begin{listing}
  \begin{minted}{haskell}
  data RCPoint = RCPoint {
    _rcp_si :: Integer
  }
  \end{minted}
  \label{ch1}
  \caption{The RCPOINT Listing}
\end{listing}

\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:eqn1}
  x^2 - 2 x
\end{equation}

I like my equation in \ref{eq:eqn1}.

I also like my code in Listing \ref{ch1}.

\end{document}
```

which compiles normally, to produces::

[image: PDF - Notice no listing number]

The reference to the listing in the final line is missing. I get a warning for the final line of output:

```
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)

Package hyperref Warning: Suppressing empty link on input line 55.

[1] (./nice-org-paper.aux) )
Output written on nice-org-paper.pdf (1 page).
Transcript written on nice-org-paper.log.
```

How do I get the reference to work?

Comment: You forget your question, in my point of view

Comment: I see who I could have clarified that.

Comment: I see now why it is marked as duplicate, but I realize that I did not even know the question to ask. I did not know about the ordering issue.

Comment: @stevejb: You did have the question in the post, but it was only in the alt text of the image: `![The question was in these square brackets](image link)`. This shows up in screen-reading software, or if the image can’t be loaded, but some (most?) people won’t see that. You can find out more on the [Markdown help page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help#images).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your `\label` occurs before your `\caption`. You should always put your `\caption` before `\label`.

The number for the listing gets assigned by `\caption`, so you should swap the two lines

```
\label{ch1}
\caption{The RCPOINT Listing}
```

to

```
\caption{The RCPOINT Listing}
\label{ch1}
```

and then your code should produce what you expect.

You can find out more about this problem in egreg’s answer to **[Why does an environment's label have to appear after the caption?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32325/why-does-an-environments-label-have-to-appear-after-the-caption)**

Comment: What's the design choice behind \caption always coming before \label?