# Table caption in uppercase. I don't know why

Tags: captions, ieeetran

```
    \documentclass{IEEEtran}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}[ht]

    \centering

    \begin{tabular}{|l|c|}

    \hline
      \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Default Parameters} \\
      \hline
    Disk Purchase cost & $\$100$ \\
    Disk Operating Cost & $\$66$ \\
    Flash Purchase Cost & $\$500$\\
    Flash Operating cost & $\$20$\\
    Duration & 100 years\\
    $K_r$& .15\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}

    \label{tab:default}
    \caption{Default parameters used for Monte Carlo Model.}
    \end{table}
    \end{document}
```

Can someone tell me why I am getting caption like this

TABLE 1
DEFAULT PARAMETERS...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! For your information, you should place `\label`s always _after_ `\caption`s (see [Why does an environment's label have to appear after the caption?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32325/why-does-an-environments-label-have-to-appear-after-the-caption)). Furthermore, IEEEtran documentation asks explicitly to put captions _before_ the table.

Comment: This is a design decision of the class you are using: as such, it's entirely to be expected.

Comment: If you're planning on submitting your document to the IEEE, I suggest you don't modify the caption style or it might annoy the editors. Journals tend to be fairly rigid about such things.

Comment: I'd like to back up @NicolaTalbot on this - don't bother annoying the editors. Also don't use journal templates for anything other than journal submissions.  However there must be a way to locally defeat the smallcaps surely: this is IEEE, so *GaAs* would be reasonable in a caption, chemical names are just plain wrong in all/small caps.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is not in upper case, but in small caps.

As other things, this is a design decision of the class you are using, as Joseph Wright points out in his comment.

But if you really want to change this behavior, you can patch the command `\@makecaption`, responsible of the caption formatting, so to don't print the caption in small caps.

That is, add the following lines to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makecaption}
  {\scshape}
  {}
  {}
  {}
\makeatother
```

Complete example (note that I've put the `\caption` at the beginning of the table, as required by `IEEEtran` AND the `\label` after it, see [Why does an environment's label have to appear after the caption?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32325/why-does-an-environments-label-have-to-appear-after-the-caption))

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makecaption}
  {\scshape}
  {}
  {}
  {}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Default parameters used for Monte Carlo Model.}
\label{tab:default}
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|}
\hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Default Parameters} \\
  \hline
Disk Purchase cost & $\$100$ \\
Disk Operating Cost & $\$66$ \\
Flash Purchase Cost & $\$500$\\
Flash Operating cost & $\$20$\\
Duration & 100 years\\
$K_r$& .15\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

If you also don't like the word "TABLE" to be upper cased, add the following line to your preamble:

```
\def\tablename{Table}
```

Output:

[image]

---

### EDIT

If you want to bring the table caption in the same line of "Table I" you also have to add the following lines in your preamble:

```
\patchcmd{\@makecaption}
  {\\}
  {.\ }
  {}
  {}
```

Change the period to whatever separator you like.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makecaption}
  {\scshape}
  {}
  {}
  {}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makecaption}
  {\\}
  {.\ }
  {}
  {}
\makeatother
\def\tablename{Table}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Default parameters used for Monte Carlo Model.}
\label{tab:default}
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|}
\hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Default Parameters} \\
  \hline
Disk Purchase cost & $\$100$ \\
Disk Operating Cost & $\$66$ \\
Flash Purchase Cost & $\$500$\\
Flash Operating cost & $\$20$\\
Duration & 100 years\\
$K_r$& .15\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks it helped. Can I bring Table 1 next to the caption?

Comment: @pretty See the edit.

Comment: @pretty You can upvote the answer, if you want ;-)

Comment: I just accidentially figured out that the same end result can be achieved by simply adding `\usepackage{subfig}`. Seems to be some strange side effect of the subfig package that it breaks the template settings for the caption.

Comment: This is almost perfect. One small thing, could you modify this command to make multi-line captions align to the left, like for figures?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can include `\usepackage{threeparttable}`, 
then use

```
\begin{table}
(table here) 

\begin{tablenotes}
\small
\item Table depicts all the things i'm talking about in this caption
\end{tablenotes}

\end{table}
```

Comment: This did work for me, but the default font style/size of the tablenotes was identical to that in the main body of the text and I would prefer something that looked different.

Answer (score -1):

As pointed out [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/373681/capitalize-the-caption-in-ieeeeqnarraybox-environment)

add:

```
\captionsetup[table]{name=TABLE,labelsep=newline,textfont=sc}
```

Comment: Isn't this doing the opposite of OP's question? OP has small caps and wants to get rid of it?