# Capitalize the caption in IEEEeqnarraybox environment

Tags: captions, subcaption

I have a problem with using `\subcaption` and `IEEEeqnarraybox` in `IEEEtran` class.

The caption should look like below along with using `\subcaption`(as it does without using `\subcaption`)

[image]

but it looks like below with using `\subcaption`
[image]

Following is MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{table}[!t]
    \centering
    \caption{This is a Caption. \label{mylabel}}
    \centering
    \begin{IEEEeqnarraybox}[
        \IEEEeqnarraystrutmode
        \IEEEeqnarraystrutsizeadd{3pt}
        {1pt}
        ]{c'c'c/v/c'c'c}
    a & b& c && d & e
        \\\hline
        1 & 3 & 3 && +1 & +1 \\
        3 & 5 & 4 && +1 & -1 \\
        2& 2& 3  && -1 & +1 \\
        4& 44& 24 && -1 & -1 \\
        4& 5 & 10 && -1 & +1 
    \end{IEEEeqnarraybox}
\end{table}

\lipsum[1-40]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Removing `subcaption` is no option, I think?

Comment: Yup, no option. I am actually using `subcaption` because of `subfigure` in my document.

Comment: Well, your 'MWE' is not using it  yet and `caption` gives a clear warning: "Unsupported document class -- don't use caption"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that the `caption` package regards the `IEEEtran` class as being not supported and gives a clear warning to refrain from using `caption` here...

However, it works with

`\captionsetup[table]{name=TABLE,labelsep=newline,justification=centering,textfont=sc}`

The `\label` has to be put outside.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]


\captionsetup[table]{name=TABLE,labelsep=newline,textfont=sc}



\begin{table}[!t]
    \centering
    \caption{This is a Caption.}
    \centering
    \begin{IEEEeqnarraybox}[
        \IEEEeqnarraystrutmode
        \IEEEeqnarraystrutsizeadd{3pt}
        {1pt}
        ]{c'c'c/v/c'c'c}
    a & b& c && d & e
        \\\hline
        1 & 3 & 3 && +1 & +1 \\
        3 & 5 & 4 && +1 & -1 \\
        2& 2& 3  && -1 & +1 \\
        4& 44& 24 && -1 & -1 \\
        4& 5 & 10 && -1 & +1 
    \end{IEEEeqnarraybox}
\end{table}

\lipsum[1-40]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But it still look like what the problem actually is. Caption should look like as in first figure in my question.

Comment: You vote for some of your new answers to return the favor of chatting help. +1

Comment: @kaka: There is `TABLE I\newline Your caption` --- that's what you wanted, see the screen shot

Comment: Caption has to be in Upper case.

Comment: @kaka: Updated the code, however, not the screen shot yet

Comment: Thank you but it is still different from the upper case as shown in first figure of the question.

Comment: @kaka: You mean small caps, not `capital letters`, actually, see the next update

Comment: Thank you. One last thing, if the caption goes long then it is not properly centered and instead justified to the left.

Comment: @kaka: Add `justification=centering` to the `\captionsetup` options, that should work

Answer (score 2):

The `caption` package is incompatible with `IEEEtran.cls`, as the warning

```
Package caption Warning: Unsupported document class (or package) detected,
(caption)                usage of the caption package is not recommended.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.
```

hints at. Copy editors at IEEE will be very annoyed by contributors trying to break the class.

If you need subfloats, you can do

```
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
```

and use `\subfloat` instead of `subfigure` (syntax change is necessary).

Comment: There are a lot of subfigures in my document to change syntax and also `subcaption` is more recent and up to date so I want to stick to `subcaption`. Thanks anyways for letting me know the inherent issue.