# Why doesn't latex recognize my figure

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

I've got a figure, which is displayed fine:

```
    \begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{xp_potato.eps}
                \caption{X and P in the complex plane}
                %\label{fig:xp_potato}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{xp_amp.eps}
                \caption{Phase modulated amplitdue}
                %\label{fig:xp_amp}
        \end{subfigure}

    \label{fig:xp}
  \caption{\textbf{Quadrature balancing problem.} ...}
\end{figure}
```

and now I would like to reference it (after the figure):

```
\hyperref[fig:xp]{Figure ~\ref{fig:xp}}
```

But I get this result: "Figure ??"

However when I click on it, my viewer jumps to the right figure. This scheme works fine through out my whole thesis. How can I fix this reference?

Comment: Looks like http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32325/why-does-an-environments-label-have-to-appear-after-the-caption to me

Comment: Maybe this related topic http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32325/why-does-an-environments-label-have-to-appear-after-the-caption may help? Place the `\label` _after_ the `\caption`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained by Joseph Wright and Ronny, this is because `\label` should go immediately after `\caption`.  Furthermore, don't forget to run a couple of times your work, as it is also necessary for `LaTeX` to get the figure numbers right (instead of `??`).