# Tables always auto ref to Table 1.2

Tags: tables, cross-referencing

When referencing a table with `\autoref{}`, instead of the table's correct reference I always get `Table 1.2`. This is quite strange, because clicking in the reference sends me to the correct table on the pdf.

Here's a sample table:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{c c c c c c}
    \hline
    Region & Facebook & Twitter & Google+ & Instagram & Pintrest \\
    \hline
    North America         & 55\% & 24\% & 17\% & 12\% & 16\% \\
    Middle East \& Africa & 52\% & 28\% & 31\% & 10\% & 8\% \\
    South America         & 51\% & 25\% & 24\% & 11\% & 6\% \\
    Asia-Pacific (APAC)   & 48\% & 27\% & 26\% & 8\% & 5\% \\
    Europe                & 43\% & 18\% & 16\% & 6\% & 3\% \\
    \hline

    \end{tabular}
\label{table:social-share-by-region}
\caption{Social network share by region, excluding China\cite{InstagramIsTheFastestGrowingSocialSiteGlobally}}
\end{table}
```

I reference it as usually:

```
\autoref{table:social-share-by-region}
```

What could be wrong?

Edit: forgot to mention; this sample table is Table 1.6, the reference (as indicated) shows Table 1.2

Edit: just tried it; `\ref{table:social-share-by-region}` is still `1.2`...

Comment: Can't say more without a complete MWE, but take a look at [Why does an environment's label have to appear after the caption?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32325/why-does-an-environments-label-have-to-appear-after-the-caption) It may well solve the problem; at the very least, it will solve other potential problems.

Comment: By the way: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: It all makes sense now! Maybe you'd like to post as an answer?