# My table is refered in Alphabetical order!

Tags: tables, cross-referencing

In my text i put my table

> \ref{table:3}

AND IN MY TABLE I START BY

> \begin{table}[H]\label{table:1} \centering

But imagine my surprise when I see my table being referred as table a in my tex...!![image]

Comment: You need to place the `\label` *after* `\caption`. See (duplicate) [Why does an environment's label have to appear after the caption?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32325/5764)

Comment: yes it works beautifully.. Thanks for replying promptly @Werner