# Wrong indentation with hanging captions

Tags: captions, indentation, koma-script

I use simple hanging captions for my tableheadings and figures. However, they are not aligned correctly. I know I can manipulate the indent manually, but I want to understand why they are placed wrong. Its not easy to see, but the second line of the caption seems to be aligned to the empty space after `:`, not to the first letter of the first line.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[captions=tableheading,14pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\captionsetup{format=hang} 

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}  


\begin{document}


\begin{table}[tbh]
\caption{\label{tab:gzf_netzbelastung_ohne} Parameter für die
Bestimmung der der Netzbelastung unter Ausschluss der Gewerbebetriebe.}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|X|}
\firsthline
Nicht berücksichtigte Haushalte & 10,29 \\\hline
Anzahl Haushalte - $n$ & 30\\\hline
$P_\mathrm{S}$ & \\
\lasthline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

Um den Einfluss der Gewerbebetriebe beurteilen zu können, sind die bei
Berücksichtigung dieser Haushalte ebenfalls bestimmt worden. Die zugehörigen
Parameter finden sich in Tabelle \ref{tab:gzf_netzbelastung_ohne}.

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

I load `subfig` because I need it in my original document - this package also loads the `caption` package. However, the same is problem arises without those packages.
I also tried leaving the redefinition of `parindent`, but this also does not change anything.

Comment: Remove `\label{...}` from inside `\caption` and put it under `\caption`, then remove the white space you typed before `\label`.

Comment: @PierPaolo thanks, works like a charm and I feel like a real idiot to forget that space. makes me wonder where the best place would be for the label? Right after `\begin{table}`?

Comment: If someone else reading this might also wonder where the best place for the `\label` is, I found an answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32325/41356

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a space after `\label{...}` which is so produced in the output.

Either

```
\caption{Parameter für die Bestimmung der der Netzbelastung unter 
  Ausschluss der Gewerbebetriebe.}\label{tab:gzf_netzbelastung_ohne}
```

or

```
\caption{Parameter für die Bestimmung der der Netzbelastung unter 
  Ausschluss der Gewerbebetriebe.\label{tab:gzf_netzbelastung_ohne}}
```

will solve the problem. I usually place the label outside (and after) `\caption`.

[image]