# Label and Ref with Table

Tags: tables, labels

I defined a Table with lable the following way:

```
\begin{table}[t]
   \centering
   \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
      \hline Transaktionsnummer & Enthaltene Items \\ 
      \hline 1 & f,a,c,d,g,i,m,p \\ 
      \hline 2 & a,b,c,f,l,m,o \\ 
      \hline 3 & b,f,h,j,o \\ 
      \hline 4 & b,c,k,s,p \\ 
      \hline 5 & a,f,c,e,l,p,m,n \\ 
      \hline 
   \end{tabular} 
   \label{tab:transaktionsdatenbank}
   \caption{Transaktionsdatenbank nach \cite{han2000mining}}
\end{table}
```

The caption shows: 
*Tabelle 5.1: Transaktionsdatenbank nach [HPY00]*

When using the reference:

```
\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{img/FrequentPatternTree58.png}
    \caption{Frequent Pattern Tree aus Transaktionsdatenbank in Tabelle \ref{tab:transaktionsdatenbank}}
    \label{fig:frequentPatternTree}
\end{figure}
```

I get:
*Abbildung 5.1: Frequent Pattern Tree aus Transaktionsdatenbank in Tabelle 5.2.2*
where 5.2.2 is the subsection the table was defined in instead of 5.1.

What could I have done wrong?

Comment: Always label behind caption.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! As Johannes says, the `\label` have to be placed after (or within) the `\caption`. See e.g. [Why does an environment's label have to appear after the caption?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32325)

Comment: This solved my problem. Thank you! (Can't +1 due to my low reputation)