# pdfLaTeX position figure at top left corner of a landscape the page

Tags: positioning

I'm new to pdfLaTeX so i could be missing something very obvious, i have looked at a few solutions none of which have worked for me.

i have a figure which is a rather large image which needs to maintain is caption and fit with the page. The image fits onto a landscape a4 page, however not matter what i have tried thus far latex renders the image from the center of the page so the figure overflows the edge of the paper.

i assume its something to do with the fact that i am using 1 landscape page when the rest are portrait so it maybe an issue with margin configuration.

heres the corresponding snippet which contains the problem(ignore the caption):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
        \centering
        \label{fig:singleton}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{class-diagram}
        \caption{Proposed high level implementation of the Singleton pattern}
    \end{figure}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

I have scaled the image to 0.8 just so its more clear where the figure is being rendered.

This is the current output:

[image]

This is the desire outcome:

[image]

[This is the image being used for the figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxo14.png)

Hopefully it is clear what the problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution. I use the `measuredfigure` environment, from `threeparttable`, to keep the caption centred with respect to the figure:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[margin=1.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelfont = sc, textfont = it}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\mbox{}\vfill
\begin{figure}[ht]
        \label{fig:singleton}
\begin{measuredfigure}
        \includegraphics[scale = 0.5]{Piero_di_Cosimo_2}
        \caption{ And now for something completely different! }
\end{measuredfigure}
    \end{figure}
\vfill\mbox{}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you. Im going to research some of the new commands you have shown me so i know exactly what they do. Just need to toy with the image size a bit to make it optimal.

Answer (score 1):

There's no real need for anything special here:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,pdflscape,lipsum,caption}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5]

\begin{landscape}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=1.3]{example-image}
  \captionof{figure}{Some caption associated with the picture}
  \label{fig:singleton}
\end{landscape}

\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

Since the `landscape` environment forms a group, you can use `\captionof{figure}{...}` to place a traditional figure caption *without* the use of the `figure` environment. The reason for avoiding the `figure` environment is because you don't want the content to float (away).

Also, always place the `\label` *after* the `\caption`; see [Why does an environment's label have to appear after the caption?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32325/5764)