# Wrong figure reference number in table

Tags: graphics, cross-referencing, captions, longtable

Hi I'm using images in longtable. To define captions in the longtable enviroment I defined this:

```
\makeatletter
\def\figcaption{%
     \refstepcounter{figure}%
     \@dblarg{\@caption{figure}}}
\makeatother
```

and then inside a cell I have

```
\parbox{5cm}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) { \includegraphics[scale=1]{image}        };
\label{fig:lol}
\end{tikzpicture}
\figcaption{my caption.}}
```

However \cite{fig:lol} gives me the table number!
Why? How can I solve it?

Edit: hyperref seems ok...

Comment: you might want to have a look at this: [Why does an environment's label have to appear after the caption?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32325)

Comment: Thank you but this is not the solution. I had already tried it... EDIT: you are right, I previously placed the label after the parbox }! Thank you so much!

Comment: you can add the answer if you want...

Comment: this is better closed as a duplicate; the question won't be removed, so it will still be searchable to help other users who have similar questions.