# \ref to algorithm/algorithmic not working

Tags: cross-referencing, algorithms, algorithmicx

I am trying to reference an algorithm in my thesis, made using the `algorithmicx` and `algorithm` packages, but it fails, ending up with the dreaded `??` and the following error:

```
LaTeX Warning: Reference `alg:somealg' on page 10 undefined on input line 442.
```

A shortened down version can be seen here:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

Blahblah, see Alg.~\ref{alg:somealg}.

\begin{algorithm}
    \label{alg:somealg}
    \caption{This is some algorithm}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \State $2 + 2 = 4$
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Always place the `\label` *after* (or within) the `\caption`.

Comment: See for example [Why does an environment's label have to appear after the caption?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32325), I guess we could close your question as a duplicate of this one?

Comment: Thanks guys, that was it! Marked this Q as being answered there.