# figure number/caption separator: colon instead of dash

Tags: floats, captions

How can I have in a figure caption `Figure 1: caption` instead of `Figure 1 - caption` ?

I tried this

```
\usepackage[labelsep=endash]{caption}
```

but didnt work.

another simple question why we should use `\label{}` after every `\caption{}` ?

**EDIT:**
here is the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[labelsep=endash]{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=.25]{image.png}
\end{center}
\caption{titre}
\label{fig:img}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\label` needs the current counter which has been increased -- the counter is increased by `\caption` (using `\refstepcounter` internally), so `\label` must come **after** `\caption`: By the way: `:` is the default

Comment: Regarding your question about "`\label` after every `\caption`": The `\label` has to go after `\caption` (see [Why does an environment's `\label` have to appear after the `\caption`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32325)), but you don't need a `\label` after *every* `\caption`; only those that you want to refer to in another part of the document.

Comment: article , fontenc babel, and of course graphicx package. i think none of them is concerned

Comment: @Christian Hupfer if `:` is the default why do i have the dash i havent modify anything or load any package that could modify it. weird ?

Comment: Just remove `labelsep=endash`, that's it. *You* are requesting an en-dash, with that option.

Comment: it was stupid from me thanks egreg i thought it does endashing(remove the dash) my bad english. now i understand i can put whatever char like `labelsep=colon`

Comment: @noob: I suppose you write in French. Traditional French typography uses an endash for separator. That's why `babel-french` sets it that way.

Comment: @noob by default it is a colon!