# Set a caption under an image in Report documentclass

Tags: graphics, report

I've been working on a report but i can't seem to find out how to get the caption of a image UNDER the specific image, instead it stays at the top of the image.
Heres my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\includegraphics[scale= 0.3]{images/MRS.jpg}
\label{fig:MRS}
\caption{A part of an MRS.}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please make your code compilable in such a way that it generates, when compiled, the problem behavior you're looking to fix. As of now, if add the instructions `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} \begin{document}` *before* `\begin{figure}` and `\end{document}` *after* `\end{figure}`, I cannot replicate the problem you say you're experiencing. For sure, though, place the `\label` instruction *after* the `\caption` directive.

Comment: [Why does an environment's `\label` have to appear after the caption?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32325/5764)

Comment: You didn't ask this question twice under different accounts, did you, by any chance?