# Why can't I put a caption in this table?

Tags: captions

I don't understand why I can't have a caption here:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\hline
\textbf{Ejemplo 3} &  \includegraphics[width=8cm,height=4cm]{figura/07.jpg} \\
\includegraphics[width=6cm,height=4cm]{figura/07_1.jpg} & \includegraphics[width=6cm,height=4cm]{figura/07_2.JPG} \\
\hline 
\textbf{Foto 7} & \includegraphics[width=8cm,height=4cm]{figura/48.jpg}\\
\includegraphics[width=6cm,height=4cm]{figura/48_1.jpg} & \includegraphics[width=6cm,height=4cm]{figura/48_2.JPG}\\
\hline
\label{casosop2}
\end{table}
\caption{caption}
\end{tabular}
```

I get the following error:

```
! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \endgroup 
l.84 \end{table}
```

If I remove the caption line, I get no problems.

Comment: I have moved caption everywhere in the code

Comment: Well an obvious problem is that your `\end{tabular}` and `\end{table}` are the wrong way around. You should have `\end{tabular}` first *and then* `\end{table}`. Anyway, I understand that you're frustrated, but please don't pepper your post with multiple exclamation marks etc. we don't like being shouted at and in any case Stackexchange sees itself as an encyclopaedic knowledge base, rather than a help group or anything

Comment: on a sidenote: rule of thumb as I know it: tables: captions above, image: captions below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A couple of things:

- Grouping follows a hierarchy: If you open up a `table` and inside it a `tabular`, you have to close the `tabular` *before* closing the `table`.
- Your `\caption` should be inside the `table` environment, not inside the `tabular`. That's just how it is, unless you're using [`longtable`](http://ctan.org/pkg/longtable).
- [Place your `\label` *after* the `\caption`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32325/5764) (and not inside the `tabular`).
  Here's what generates your table:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,float}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
    \hline
    \textbf{Ejemplo 3} &  \includegraphics[width=8cm,height=4cm]{example-image-a} \\
    \includegraphics[width=6cm,height=4cm]{example-image-b} & \includegraphics[width=6cm,height=4cm]{example-image-c} \\
    \hline
    \textbf{Foto 7} & \includegraphics[width=8cm,height=4cm]{example-image-a}\\
    \includegraphics[width=6cm,height=4cm]{example-image-b} & \includegraphics[width=6cm,height=4cm]{example-image-c}\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{caption}
  \label{casosop2}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```