# Figure numbering follows sections

Tags: numbering, lncs

I am using the `llncs` document class.

And my figures are being numbered in a manner I do not understand. I define and place the figure like this:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{myBirds.png}
    \label{fig:thebirds}
    \caption{The birds}
\end{figure}
```

The captions count as I expect it:

> --Image--
>
> Fig. 1. The birds
>
> --Image--
>
> Fig. 2. The Ants

So Latex has an idea of the correct number of figures. But when I look at the references in the text, numbers are not correct. They just show the section number. e.g. in section 7, all figures will be referred to as `Figure 7`.

Note: I **do NOT have** something like

```
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
```

Comment: Welcome! Don't. This class is intended for conference/journal submission. If you override its design, you'll just annoy the copy editor. It is designed to impose house style on your document. If you aren't submitting, use a more flexible class which is designed to permit you to customise relevant aspects of its design.

Comment: The default for [`llncs`](ftp://ftp.springer.de/pub/tex/latex/llncs/latex2e/llncs2e.zip) does not follow this convention. What are you doing differently that is causing this?

Comment: @Werner it seems that you are right. I described it better with the new Edit.

Comment: @MakanTayebi: The obvious problem here is that you have `\label` *before* `\caption` inside your `figure`. You need `\label` *after* `\caption`. See [Why does an environment's label have to appear after the caption?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32325/5764) (duplicate)