# What does amsmath do to \@currentlabel?

Tags: cross-referencing, align, amsmath

Can someone explain what `amsmath` does to `\@currentlabel` in the `align` environments?

Better yet: if I want to write what would be expected to be the `\@currentlabel` together with some other information into an auxiliary output file, what's the best way to access that information in the `align` environments?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\storelabel[1]{%
    \xdef#1{\@currentlabel}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    A = B  \storelabel{\firstone}
\end{equation}
Now
\begin{align}
    C &= D \storelabel{\secondone}\\
    C' &= D' \storelabel{\thirdone}
\end{align}
\begin{equation}
    E = F \storelabel{\fourthone}
\end{equation}
The counters are \firstone, \secondone, \thirdone, \fourthone.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why don't you just use `\label` and `\ref`?

Comment: The `\storelabel` command is executed before the equation number is set, i.e. `\@currentlabel` is just empty! The reason it works for `equation` is that `\inc@eqnum` is used right at the begin of the environment, not in the `\toks@` token register at the very end

Comment: @HenriMenke because I am trying to write into an auxiliary file. The output of `\ref{label}`, as far as I know, is not "just" the counter value. `\typeout{\ref{equation1}}` yields something like `1\hbox {}`. If you have an idea how I can just use `\ref` to get only the reference number that I can stuff into an auxiliary file, I'd also welcome that solution. (I don't mind having to run `pdflatex` multiple times.)

Comment: @WillieWong: You can use the `\getrefnumber` command from `refcount` package -- that is expandable, `\ref` isn't

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: That's awesome. I didn't know about that package. While that doesn't answer the question I asked, it answers the question I should've asked. If you can edit your last comment as an alternate part to your answer below (or as a second answer), I'll accept it.

Comment: @WillieWong: Added to the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behaviour of `\refstepcounter` in `equation` and `align` (for example) is different in the sense that

- in `equation` the `\incr@eqnum` command (a wrapper for `\refstepcounter` etc.) is used right at the start of the environment, so `\storelabel` can access `\@currentlabel`
- in `align` however, the `\storelabel` command is used before the `tag` is set, i.e. `\@currentlabel` is just empty at that time of usage.

Either the `\make@display@tag` command is patched or shortly redefined where the shifted definition of `\xdef...{\@currentlabel}` is used after `\incr@eqnum`.

The `\storelabel` command is actually a fake command now, just defining the next name to be set, but the true definition of the macro name is done later on.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\extractstoretag}{%
  \@ifundefined{nextstoretag}{%
  }{%
    \expandafter\xdef\csname \nextstoretag\endcsname{\@currentlabel}
    \let\nextstoretag\relax
  }%
}
\AtEndEnvironment{equation}{%
  \extractstoretag%
}

\def\make@display@tag{%
  \if@eqnsw \incr@eqnum \extractstoretag \print@eqnum
  \else \iftag@ \df@tag \global\let\df@tag\@empty \fi
  \fi
  \ifmeasuring@
  \else
    \ifx\df@label\@empty
    \else
      \@xp\ltx@label\@xp{\df@label}%
      \global\let\df@label\@empty
    \fi
  \fi
}


\newcommand\storelabel[1]{%
  \xdef\nextstoretag{#1}%
}%
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    A = B  \storelabel{firstone}
  \end{equation}
  Now
\begin{align}
    C  &= D   \storelabel{secondone} \\
    C' &= D'  \storelabel{thirdone}
\end{align}
\begin{equation}
    E = F \storelabel{fourthone}
\end{equation}
The counters are \firstone, \secondone, \thirdone,\fourthone.
\end{document}
```

Here's the version with `\.....` macros in the `\storelabel` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter


\newcommand{\extractstoretag}{%
  \@ifundefined{nextstoretag}{%
    \relax%
  }{%
    \expandafter\xdef\csname \nextstoretag\endcsname{\@currentlabel}
    \let\nextstoretag\relax
  }%
}
\AtEndEnvironment{equation}{%
  \extractstoretag%
}

\def\make@display@tag{%
  \if@eqnsw \incr@eqnum \extractstoretag \print@eqnum
  \else \iftag@ \df@tag \global\let\df@tag\@empty \fi
  \fi
  \ifmeasuring@
  \else
    \ifx\df@label\@empty
    \else
      \@xp\ltx@label\@xp{\df@label}%
      \global\let\df@label\@empty
    \fi
  \fi
}


\newcommand{\storelabel}[1]{%
    \xdef\nextstoretag{\expandafter\@gobble\string#1}%
  }%
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    A = B  \storelabel{\firstone}
  \end{equation}

  \begin{align}
    C  &= D   \storelabel{\secondone} \\
    C' &= D'  \storelabel{\thirdone}
  \end{align}
  \begin{equation}
    E = F \storelabel{\fourthone}
\end{equation}


The counters are \firstone, \secondone, \thirdone\ and \fourthone.
\end{document}
```

**Update/Edit**

Apparently, another solution to get the 'real' content what is written to the `.aux` file can be achieved by using the `\getrefnumber` from the package `refcount` by Heiko Oberdiek.

Comment: Apparently my solution is worse than the other one :-(

Answer (score 5):

From the [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsmath.pdf) (section **15.2 Implementing tags and labels**, p 39):

> Sometimes it is necessary for a `\tag` command to store a tag in a safe place
>   and to process it later, e.g., for a tag in a row of an alignment where the tag
>   can only be typeset when the `\\` at the end of the row was seen. Such a tag is
>   stored in the macro `\df@tag` (for ‘`d`e`f`erred `tag`’). For this purpose we provide
>   the `\make@df@tag` macro. It is built very similar to the `\maketag@@` macro [..].
>
> ```
> \let\df@tag\@empty
> \def\make@df@tag{\@ifstar\make@df@tag@@\make@df@tag@@@}
> ```
>
> `\make@df@tag` sets `\@currentlabel` and defines `\df@tag` appropriately.
>
> To simplify the task of tracking `\tag` and `\label` commands inside math display
>   environments, we defer `\label` commands until the tag is typeset, similar
>   to the way that `\tag`s themselves are deferred. This allows arbitrary placement
>   of `\label` and `\tag` commands and also means we only increment the `\equation`
>   counter when we really need to, thus avoiding the `\setb@ck` nonsense that used
>   to be required.
>
> ```
> \def\make@df@tag@@#1{%
>   \gdef\df@tag{\maketag@@@{#1}\def\@currentlabel{#1}}}
> ```
>
> Autogenerated number:
>
> ```
> \def\make@df@tag@@@#1{\gdef\df@tag{\tagform@{#1}%
>   \toks@\@xp{\p@equation{#1}}\edef\@currentlabel{\the\toks@}}}
> ```

The crucial part of the above discussion is the mention that within a display, `amsmath` takes control of the `\label` and `\tag`, deferring the former until the tag has been set. It allows for ease-of-use from a user's perspective<sup>*</sup>.

So you will either have to tap into the setting of the tag in order to extract the correct `\@currentlabel`, or you'll have to stick to using a `\label`-`\ref` system. [`refcount`](http://ctan.org/pkg/refcount) is another option for extracting the reference in an expandable way, still using a `\label`-`\ref`-like setup:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,refcount}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  A = B  \label{firstone}
\end{equation}
Now
\begin{align}
  C &= D \label{secondone} \\
  C' &= D' \label{thirdone}
\end{align}
\begin{equation}
  E = F \label{fourthone}
\end{equation}
The counters are \getrefnumber{firstone}, \getrefnumber{secondone}, \getrefnumber{thirdone}, \getrefnumber{fourthone}.

\end{document}
```

<sub><sup>*</sup>In an analogous (yet opposite) way there's no control over the placement of the `\caption` inside a float - it's set inline with the placement. As such, the user has to make sure that [`\label` comes *after* the `\caption`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32325/5764); `amsmath` tries to accommodate the user by allowing them to place `\label` wherever inside the display - before *or* after the `\tag` even without a `\tag`.</sub>