# Can I set a custom behavior for labels?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, amsmath

I want each chapter to have a closed set of labels, meaning that different chapters can contain the same label, and if I use `\eqref` in that chapter, only look for the label in that same chapter, otherwise say "not defined label". In summary, I want each chapter to have independent label. Can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You're going to shoot at your own feet with this.

Comment: Are you using [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)?

Comment: @Werner Yes I am using hyperref. But if I could, I would use it only for headers, and not for equations. At the moment, hyperref is referring to the closest label it finds, I think.

Comment: @egreg Why do you think that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a macro  to automatically add `chap<chapternumber>:` before each label, and change `\ref` so that it searches for references with `chap<chapternumber>:`prefix.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\let\normallabel\label
\let\normalref\ref

\makeatletter
% Poor man's version of ConTeXt's \expanded macro
\newcommand\expanded[1]
    {\xdef\EXPANDED@MACRO{\noexpand#1}\EXPANDED@MACRO}
\makeatother

\newcommand\customlabel[1]
    {\expanded{\normallabel{chap\thechapter:#1}}}

\newcommand\customref[1]
    {\normalref{chap\thechapter:#1}}

\let\ref\customref
\let\label\customlabel

% AMSMath changes the behavior of label.
\makeatletter
\let\ltx@label\customlabel
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:first}
  a = b + c
\end{equation}

It is shown in \eqref{eq:first} (\ref{eq:first}) that \ldots

\chapter{Second chapter}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:first}
  a = b + c
\end{equation}

It is shown in \eqref{eq:first} (\ref{eq:first}) that \ldots
\end{document}
```

If you open `filename.aux` file, you'll see:

```
\relax 
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}First chapter}{1}}
\@writefile{lof}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\@writefile{lot}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\newlabel{chap1:eq:first}{{1.1}{1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {2}Second chapter}{3}}
\@writefile{lof}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\@writefile{lot}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\newlabel{chap2:eq:first}{{2.1}{3}}
```

Thus, the labels are written as `{chap1:eq:first}`, `{chap2:eq:first}`, etc. So, they are unique per chapter.

Comment: The way the `ams` packages typeset tags and labels are... tricky. See the answers to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319158/what-does-amsmath-do-to-currentlabel for example.

Comment: @WillieWong: Thanks for the explanation! I have updated the answer.

Comment: @Aditya Thank you very much! I changed your answer a little, but everything is working fine!

Comment: Question: would you consider using this yourself? You don't mention any of the downsides of doing thing or the potential pitfalls.

Comment: @BrunoMurino Did you try `\usepackage{hyperref}`?

Comment: @cfr I already use hyperref.

Comment: @BrunoMurino That's why I asked. If I add `hyperref` to this example, it doesn't work. At least, `hyperref` works. But the references are not as you want. (I don't think you should want this - I agree with egreg - but since you do.)

Comment: @crf I don't know, I simplified that code a little and everything is working really fine.

Comment: @cfr: I won't use something like this myself but that is because I don't mind using unique references. I don't understand LaTeX internals well enough to know the pitfalls of what I view as a simple hack.

Comment: @BrunoMurino Interesting. It didn't work for me when I added `hyperref`.

Comment: @cfr I don't know, I didn't use that expand macro, I just defined a newcommand that always adds \thechapter on the argument of \label... , and of course a similar command for \ref... I believe that in my case hyperref feels noting different, since the labels are always different

Comment: @BrunoMurino Oh. So you just use `\customlabel` and `\customref` directly?

Comment: @cfr Yes, pretty much it!