# A problem adding caption to a figure

Tags: floats, captions

I'm using the following packages on Overleaf:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
```

When I try adding a caption there's a compilation error (caption outside float). Here's what I'm doing:

```
\begin{center}
\label {tab1}
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{fig.PNG} \caption{cap_text}
\end{center}
```

How can I fix that problem?

By the way I need two texts, one above, one under the figure. Should I just add `\caption{text}` before and after it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`center` is not a floating environment, hence the error. You need the `figure` environment instead, i.e.

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{..}
\caption{..}
\label{..}
\end{figure}
```

I'm assuming only one of the texts need to be part of the numbered caption, for the other just add some text in the appropriate location, e.g.

```
\begin{figure}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, etc., etc.

\centering
\includegraphics{..}
\caption{..}
\label{..}
\end{figure}
```

If you don't need the image to float, you can continue using `center` instead of `figure`, but add `\usepackage{caption}` to the preamble, and use `\captionof{figure}{caption text \label{...}}` instead of `\caption`. Note that the `\label` has to be placed after or within the `\caption`, otherwise cross-references wont work, see e.g. [Why does an environment's label have to appear after the caption?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32325)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics{..}
\captionof{figure}{...\label{..}}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

As pagebreaks are allowed inside a `center` environment, you could here end up with image and caption on separate pages, which is probably not wanted. An alternative is to use a `minipage` instead of `center`, e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics{..}
\captionof{figure}{...\label{..}}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

The `\noindent` is to remove the standard paragraph indentation.