# Referencing a subfigure, gives section referencing

Tags: captions, subfloats

I am trying to referencing a different subfigures in the following LaTeX with the clever reference

```
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{.49\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=.49]{test_data/test_data1}
    \label{fig:first-score}
    \caption{}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{.49\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=.49]{test_data/test_data2}
    \label{fig:second-score}
    \caption{}
  \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.49\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=.49]{test_data/score_combibed_test_data}
    \label{fig:score-combined}
    \caption{}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Score test data}
  \label{fig:score-res}
\end{figure}
```

Then when I do `\cref{fig:first-score}` it reference the section instead of the subfigure. What should I do to get it to refence the subfiugre? 
I have include the subcaption package.

Comment: `\label` always *after* (or within) `\caption`.

Comment: See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32325/why-does-an-environments-label-have-to-appear-after-the-caption