# Spacing between table and caption

Tags: tables, spacing, captions

Hi when producing this table, there's a huge gap between the caption and the table.
Any way I can remove this?

```
\begin{table}[H]  
{  
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}  
\begin{center}  
\begin{tabular}{ c c c c c c }  
\textbf{\textit{Source}} & \textbf{\textit{DF}}&\textbf{\textit{SS}}&   \textbf{\textit{MS}} & \textbf{\textit{F-Value}} & \textbf{\textit{Pr  \textgreater F }}\\  
\hline  
\hline  
\( Treatment\) & 2 & 470094755.9 & 235047378.0 & 61.94 & \textless .0001\\  
\( Residual\) & 57 & 216313345.8 & 3794971.0 & &\\  
\hline   
\( Total\) & 59 & 686408101.7 & & &  \\  
\label{fig:Data Set 1 - One-Way ANOVA by Operating Region}  
\end{tabular}  
\end{center}  
}  
\caption{Data Set 1 - One-Way ANOVA by Operating Region}  
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `center` environment adds vertical space and [shouldn't be used in a float](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2651/82917). Apart from that, you are making a new line and calling `\label` within the `tabular` environment. This has two bad consequences:

1. you lose the label, since [the corresponding counter is increased by `\caption`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32325/82917).
2. You are basically putting an empty tabular row, which will look like extra vertical space.

A slightly improved version of your code would then be

```
\begin{table}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}  
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ c c c c c c }  
\textbf{\textit{Source}} & \textbf{\textit{DF}}&\textbf{\textit{SS}}&   \textbf{\textit{MS}} & \textbf{\textit{F-Value}} & \textbf{\textit{Pr \textgreater{} F }}\\  
\hline  
\hline  
\textit{Treatment} & 2 & 470094755.9 & 235047378.0 & 61.94 & \textless .0001\\  
\textit{Residual} & 57 & 216313345.8 & 3794971.0 & &\\  
\hline   
\textit{Total} & 59 & 686408101.7 & & &  \\  
\end{tabular}  
\caption{Data Set 1 - One-Way ANOVA by Operating Region}
\label{fig:Data Set 1 - One-Way ANOVA by Operating Region}  
\end{table}
```