# Correct numbering and reference for appendix

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing, listings, numbering, appendices

In my paper, I tried to create an appendix and refer to it from the main text.

I tried to post it a very easy example. It does not depend on the journal class thus I don't know what's wrong with this simple syntax.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,draft]{article}
\usepackage{pslatex,graphicx}

%opening
\title{bla bla}
\author{a, b, c}
%
\begin{document}
%
\maketitle
%
\begin{abstract}
ipse dixit 
\end{abstract}
%
\section{ introduction}
%
In Figs.~\ref{figA1}, \ref{figB1}, \ref{figC1}
% Should be: In Figs. 1, 2, 3
\section*{Appendix}
%
\appendix
%
\begin{figure*}
 \centerline{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{figureB1.png}}
 \label{figA1}
\caption{Ipse dixit...} 
\end{figure*}

\begin{figure*}
 \centerline{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{figureA1.png}}
 \label{figB1}
\caption{See Fig.~\ref{figA1}.} %Should be "See Fig. 1" 
\end{figure*}

\begin{figure*}
 \centerline{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{figureC4.png}}
 \label{figC1}
\caption{See Fig.~\ref{figB1}.}  %Should be "See Fig. 2"
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

I add two explicative images here:

[image: one]

shows the numbering in the main part of the text. Which should be "1, 2, 3" not "1, 1, 1" and the

[image: other]

shows the reference calling in the  appendix itself which, again, is wrong.

Many thanks in advice for your help.

Comment: \label has to be placed after \caption... try it!

Comment: @koleygr ok, I am a donkey :-) many many thanks.

Comment: Off-topic: Why are you loading the badly-deprecated `pslatex` package? The package's user guide, which hasn't been updated in more than 2 decades, states that `pslatex` is deprecated. If you must use a Times Roman clone in your document, and assuming that you have access to a reasonably modern TeX distributon (i.e., a vintage more recent than ca 2012), you should look into loading the `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` packages. (If your TeX distribution is more than 6 years old, do yourself a big favor and update to something more up-to-date.)

Comment: this question might be considered, if not a duplicate, then guidance for the next person looking for help on the subject: [Why does an environment's label have to appear after the caption?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32325)

Comment: @barbarabeeton yes eventually you are right. It could be a duplicate btw I considered answered my question. Thanks everybody for the answers.