# Can't \ref PGFPlot

Tags: cross-referencing

I'm attempting to reference a `figure` containing a `tikzpicture` from `pgfplots`. However, for some reason, I'm getting ?? instead of the figure number when I `\ref` it.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

The section is below:

```
\subsection{Graph of Results}
Figure \ref{fig:ResultsGraph} shows the data gathered in Table \ref{tbl:ResultsData}.
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[legend pos=north east,anchor=west, xlabel={$\dfrac{1}{T} / K^{-1}$}, ylabel={$ln P*_a$}]
\addplot table [only marks, x=1/T,y=lnPa]{GraphData.txt};
\addplot [thick, red] table[y={create col/linear regression={y=lnPa}}]{GraphData.txt};
\addlegendentry{$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \pgfplotstableregressiona$}
\addlegendentry{$y_{intercept} = \pgfplotstableregressionb$}
\end{axis}
\label{fig:ResultsGraph}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Graph to show the relationship between the natural log of pressure and the inverse of temperature}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: `\label` should appear after `\caption` - see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32325/why-does-an-environments-label-have-to-appear-after-the-caption).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As greyshade said, the `\label` should appear after the `\caption`.

You may have put `\label` inside the `tikzpicture` environment with the intuition that the picture itself is what you're labeling and referring to. But from LaTeX's point of view, what you're labeling and referring to is the figure's caption. So putting `\label` outside the `tikzpicture` environment, between the `\caption` and the `\end{figure}`, will do what you need.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you're referring to the `\caption`, not the `figure` environment. There can be more than one `\caption` in the same `figure`.