# Image references

Tags: cross-referencing

I want to add a reference to an image or a table that is after the text but it seams that the compiler is not finding the label, giving me "??" as number, like the label is not existing. It works only if I put the image before the text.
Why is it happening and how can I solve it?

```
as shown in figure \ref{text} ...

\begin{figure}[H] \centering \label{text}
    {\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{figure/image}}
    \caption[dsad]{dsad}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Did you compile twice to resolve cross-references?

Comment: What do you mean? Everytime that I add something I recompile. Or do I need to cancel temporal files generated when compiles?

Comment: I mean that when you add a reference, you have to compile twice. Normally, you don't have to delete temporary files, but it may depend on the  loaded packages.

Comment: Yes I did. Still not working.

Comment: Could you post a small code illustrating this  problem?

Comment: No problem, I thought that was clear enough the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `\label` after the `\caption`

```
\begin{document}
    as shown in figure \ref{text} ...

    \begin{figure}[H] 
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.48\textwidth]{figure/image}
        \caption[dsad]{dsad}
        \label{text}
    \end{figure}
\end{document
```

You can find some information about this here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32326/105976

Also you don't need that extra brackets around `\includegrahics`, and you don't need to set `keepaspectratio`,when only setting the `width` the ratio will be the same