# How to cross reference between tex files

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, external-files, autoref

I have looked at all the previously posted answers. None have answered my questions. This is my example:

I have a main document called `paper.tex`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}


\begin{document}

\title{Title}

\begin{abstract}
Abstract  
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{Test}
\label{sec:test}
\input{sec/test}

\end{document}
```

In `test.tex`, I have two other documents:

```
\subsection{Test One} \label{sec:test1}
\input{sec/test1}

\subsection{Test Two} \label{sec:test2}
\input{sec/test2}
```

The `test.tex` contains a figure:

```
\begin{figure*}[tp!]
\label{fig:fig1}
\centering
\caption{My Figure}
\end{figure*}
```

I want to reference the figure from `test2.tex`:

```
\externaldocument{test1}

As show in \autoref{fig:fig1}.
```

Unfortunately, the output is not referencincing the figure as `Figure 1`, but as: `subsection 1.1`

Can you please correct my example?

Comment: This isn't because of input/include.  The label always needs to come after the caption.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32325/107497