# Unable to reference table from input file

Tags: cross-referencing

I've separated my large tables into other individual files for organization and ease of editing, but I can't seem to reference any of them. Can someone clue me into what is going on?

main.tex

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

    \input{a.tex}

    Table~\ref{tab:test}

\end{document}
```

a.tex

```
\begin{table}[!htb]
    \centering
    \caption{ Test }
    \label{test}
\end{table}
```

My understanding is that if the label isn't duplicated I should be able to reference this. Without it turning into `??`

[image]

** Update **

Even the xr package doesn't seem to help as other answers have suggested.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xr}
\externaldocument[a-]{a}

\begin{document}


    \input{a.tex}

    Table\ref{a-test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Move `\label{test}` after `\caption{ Test }`.

Comment: No dice, why would order matter?

Comment: [That's why](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32325/121799).

Comment: Okay, I'll do that from now on but it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Did you compile twice?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I've compiled using TeXstudio and also tried deleting the AUX file with no success.

Comment: Well, the process that converts a tex file into a pdf is called compiling. You set `\label{test}` but do `\ref{tab:test}`. Use `\label{tab:test}` instead.

Comment: Yes I have compiled multiple times. Does the MWE work for you? I went to the trouble of creating it. This is only a problem with referencing tables, figures, etc from a `\input`. Keeping the table within the same file works but is undesirable.

Answer (score 5):

This is not an answer, just to say: yes, it works. Your original file had two issues:

1. `\label` was before `\caption`, but [this does not work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32325/121799).
2. You label the table `\label{test}` but refer to it with `\ref{tab:test}`. However, you need to use the same label as reference.

After fixing the issues, it works.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{a.tex}
\begin{table}[!htb]
    \centering
    \caption{ Test }
    \label{tab:test}
\end{table}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}

    \input{a.tex}

    Table~\ref{tab:test}

\end{document}
```

[image]