# Problems with referencing in Emacs/RefTeX

Tags: cross-referencing, captions, auctex, reftex

I have problems referencing a table (see Example below) using GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 1, x86_64-w64-mingw32) on Windows Pro X64 and AUCTeX with RefTeX. If I set a label, and reference it, the reference will not appear in the text (either `??` or nothing at all). This can be seen in the buffer `*RefTeX Select*`

> ```
>           tbl:tabco2
> .                 NO MATCH FOR CONTEXT REGEXP
> ```

Any idea what is going wrong (older labels in the file this appeared still work properly).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
   \centering
     \begin{tabular}{lr}
        Energy commodity & t CO2/TJ \\
        Light fuel oil & 73.70 \\
        Heavy fuel oil & 77.00 \\
     \end{tabular}
     \label{tbl:tabco2}
     \caption{CO$_2$ factors of energy commodities.}
 \end{table}

 This is table \ref{tbl:tabco2}

 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\label` should be placed after the `\caption`, for it's the latter which generates the number `\label` refers to (see [Why does an environment's label have to appear after the caption?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32325/105447)). As a matter of fact, `\label` will always refer to the *previous* generated reference number in the document. `RefTeX` also applies this logic, in searching for the context to display: It starts after `\label` and searches backward for the regular expressions defined in the variable `reftex-default-context-regexps`.  In sum, just put your `\label` *after* the `\caption`, for it to have something to reference, that's what both `RefTeX` and `latex` expect.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{lr}
    Energy commodity & t CO2/TJ \\
    Light fuel oil & 73.70 \\
    Heavy fuel oil & 77.00 \\
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{CO$_2$ factors of energy commodities.}
  \label{tbl:tabco2}
\end{table}

This is table \ref{tbl:tabco2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I edited your answer slightly as I didn't want to write a new one.  I hope this is OK for you.

Comment: @ArashEsbati Thank you for your edit, it's a welcome addition, and it clears up how RefTeX uses such information. But I should add still something to complement, because the original code also produced a latex error, it is not only RefTeX which looses the reference.