# Figure labels and references with \adjustimage

Tags: graphics, labels

I am wondering why this command works:

```
\noindent\adjustimage{width=1.2\textwidth,center,caption={mycaption},label={mylabel},figure}{mylabel}
```

and I got references working correctly, and instead with this code I get the document compiled, but references do not work (question marks appear):

```
\begin{figure}
\adjustimage{width=1.2\textwidth,center}{myfigure}
\label{mylabel}
\caption{mycaption}
\end{figure}
```

In there any way to modify the above code in order to have references working?

I add a minimal code that allow compilation:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx,float}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}
In picture reference \ref{figure1} works, instead in picture \ref{figure2} does not 
\noindent\adjustimage{width=1.2\textwidth,center,caption={mycaption1},label={figure1},figure}{myfigure1}
\begin{figure}[H]
        \adjustimage{width=1.2\textwidth,center}{myfigure2}
        \label{figure2}
        \caption{mycaption2}
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you pease make your example code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages? How/where is `\adjustimage` defined?

Comment: \adjustimage is part of the adjustbox package; I have added a minimal code that allow compilation, maybe all packages are not really needed (I am using pdflatex with .eps images)

Comment: Thanks a lot, since I am pretty new in the use of adjustbox package I was misleaded in the search for a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in [Why does an environment's label have to appear after the caption?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32325/82917), the `\label` must, well, appear *after* the `\caption`. In this case the `caption` package even issues a warning

```
Package caption Warning: \label without proper reference on input line 11.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.
```

Unrelated: in a TeX distribution which is not completely outdated it is not necessary to load the `epstopdf` package.