# Table and figure numbering are wrong

Tags: pdftex, numbering, document-classes, article

I am using the following code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,onecolumn,twoside,draftcls]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{placeins}

\let\Oldsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}{\FloatBarrier\Oldsection}
\let\Oldsubsection\subsection
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\FloatBarrier\Oldsubsection}
\let\Oldsubsubsection\subsubsection
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\FloatBarrier\Oldsubsubsection}

\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,filecontents}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[pagewise]{lineno}

\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} 

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\listoftables

See Figs.~\ref{fig:1} and~\ref{fig:2} and Tables~\ref{table:1} and~\ref{table:2}.

\section{section 1}
\section{section 2} \label{sec4}
\begin{table}[H] \label{table:1} 
    \caption{table 1 caption}
\end{table}
\begin{figure} [H]\label{fig:1}
    \caption{fig 1 caption}
\end{figure}

\subsection{subsection}
\begin{table}[H] \label{table:2} 
    \caption{table 2 caption}
\end{table}
\begin{figure} [H]\label{fig:2}
    \caption{fig 2 caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

When I compile, I see that the table numberings are correct in the table, but wrong when I refer to them. They get the number of their section/subsection. The same thing happens for figure numberings as well:

```
List of Figures
1 fig 1 caption . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 1
2 fig 2 caption . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 1
List of Tables
1 table 1 caption . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 1
2 table 2 caption . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 1
See Figs. 2 and 2.1 and Tables 2 and 2.1.
1 section 1
2 section 2
Table 1: table 1 caption
Figure 1: fig 1 caption
2.1 subsection
Table 2: table 2 caption
Figure 2: fig 2 caption 1
```

I need that the table numberings become independent of the section/subsection. The numbering starts at 1, and when I add a new table, it increases by 1. The same when I refer to them. I want the same thing for figure numberings as well. Can you help?

---

I got a comment that the label has to be placed after the caption. I did that but nothing changed. The same issue is there. So, this is not duplicate.

---

Edit after the second comment: I fixed it. The label has to be placed right after the caption.  What I did and did not work was placing the label after caption, but it was not right after the caption. It was after the \end{figure} or \end{table}. When I put it right after the caption, it works.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  You've got a common problem -- the `\label` commands are input before the `\caption` for each table.  It's the caption that resets the numbering, so placing the label before the caption will refer to whatever the previous element was that has a referenceable number.  (This is certainly a duplicate; I'll look for a suitable one.)

Comment: Duplicate: [Why does an environment's label have to appear after the caption?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32325)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks. But, this is not the case. Please see my edit above.

Comment: Did you rerun twice?  The label information is written out to the `.aux` file in the first run, and read back in in the second run.  Unless you delete the `.aux` file(s) first (which will force you to run the job twice, and which I should have mentioned earlier), you will still be getting the "old" values.  So the safest approach is to delete the `.aux` file(s) before rerunning.  If this doesn't change anything, something is seriously wrong.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Yes, I rerun it twice and even deleted the .aux file twice. Nothing changed.

Comment: After moving the labels in the posted example, the references are correct.  I can't reproduce the problem you report.

Comment: what do you mean by "see my edit above" ? Your example clearly shows `\label` in teh wrong place, before `\caption` you have `\label{fig:1}
    \caption{fig 1 caption}`

Comment: note that while it works it is usually bad practice to use a numeric label such as `fig:2` as the label has no connection to the printed number and it's confusing to  look at the source if Figure 4 has  label `fig:3`

Comment: @barbarabeeton What I did and did not work was placing the label after caption, but it was not right after the caption. It was after the \end{figure} or \end{table}. Then, I put it right after the caption and now it works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, David. I realized what I have to do. I have edited my question again. What is your suggestion for labeling?

Comment: @Albert the label is an internal identifier for the content not the final number, so `\label{fermat}`  then `\ref{fermat}` will make whatever number fermat's last theorem gets in the final presentation.

Comment: @Albert -- It's sometimes recommended to put the label inside the caption, and that also works, but it's not my preference.  If there is a list of tables/figures, the caption is used for that, and I'm not sure what effect a label in that position might have in the list.