# TeX: \ref using wrapfig wraptable calls section number instead of table number

Tags: tex-core

I have a problem using the `wrapfigure` package. As you'll see in the code example below, when I call `\ref{My table}` what I get is a reference to the section I am in instead of the table.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

    \section{Section}

    \subsection{Subsection}

    \begin{wraptable}{l}{0pt}
        \begin{tabular}{cccc}
        A & B & C & D \\
        E & F & G &  H\\        
        \end{tabular}
    \label{My table}\caption{This is my table.}
    \end{wraptable}

\textbf{Table \ref{My table} should be called Table 1.}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image: Reference problem using wrapfig package]

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't ask multiple different questions in one post. Can you move your secondary question into a new post?

Comment: Done! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61370235/tex-wrapfig-package-problem-aligning-text

Comment: One of the most commonly reported problems.  The explanation is here: [Why does an environment's label have to appear after the caption?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32325)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a simple workaround, you can place the label within the caption:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

    \section{Section}

    \subsection{Subsection}

    \begin{wraptable}{l}{0pt}
        \begin{tabular}{cccc}
        A & B & C & D \\
        E & F & G &  H\\        
        \end{tabular}
    \caption{\label{Mytable}This is my table.}
    \end{wraptable}

\textbf{Table \ref{Mytable} should be called Table 1. The text should also begin aligned with the table's top row.}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

(don't use spaces in labels)

Comment: That does work, thanks a lot. Thanks for the tip on spaces :). What is the etiquette though, should I leave it with your comment in case it can help anyone or fix it?

Comment: That's not a "workaround" though. It is a rule in LaTeX for all figures and tables: the `\label` needs to go in or after the caption, because the caption does the numbering.https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32325/why-does-an-environments-label-have-to-appear-after-the-caption

Comment: Thanks @DonaldArseneau. How do you choose between tex.stackexchange and stackoverflow when it comes to LaTeX questions?