# Problem with references of a figure

Tags: floats

I am writing a report and I am trying to get a reference to a figure. The code for my fig is:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \label{fig:eloss}
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.32]{figs/eloss.jpg}
    \end{center}
    \caption{\small Histogramme}
\end{figure}
```

and to refer to it I use `\ref{fig:eloss}`
The result that I get in a text is `??` but because I use `\hyperref` when I click on it it gets me to the right figure. But still I want to have the proper text. 
The reference command works perfectly for equations.

Comment: I guess you have remembered to recompile twice? Perhaps moving the \label to after the caption will help.

Comment: Yes apparently the label has to go after the caption. Thank you very much :-)

Comment: Potential duplicate: [Why does an environment's label have to appear after the caption?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32325)